# Is there any way to detect what external libraries an Android app contains?

Tags: android, android-library

I am trying to make an Android app that could identify if an app in my device has certain external libraries installed, i.e. google analytics or flurry, but I have not found anything yet on how such thing could be done.

The only relative thing I found what this AppBrain app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.detector), which identifies this specific information.

Has anyone any insights on that issue? I suppose I could monitor specific parameters for each library (i.e. network calls, or permissions in the manifest) but I do not believe this is the correct way.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: hmm.  Well, the external jars will be stored in the /libs/ directory in the apk.  No clue how, but maybe you could find a way to access that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is not.  This is a security restriction on Android.